# How to add a txt filter to my save button code

Tags: vb.net

I am developing an application to grab photos from web. I have the save button working. However, when I try to save I need to input the name and abbreviation after the name like this example name.txt
how can i add the filter to my saving code?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    If My.Application.CommandLineArgs IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count > 0 Then
        Dim UserFile As String = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)


    End If

    If SaveFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

        For Each o As Object In LstMain.Items
            sb.AppendLine(o)
        Next

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(SaveFD.FileName, sb.ToString())
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question with more examples? It is really hard to understand what you are asking. Do you mean extension when you say "abbreviation"?

Comment: Sorry for that confusion

Comment: well its simple what i ask is:

Comment: wen i press the button for save the list-box items to a text file , every thing is work but wen the save dialog windows open there is no choose to apply on the save method like for example mytextlinks and its should automatic add .txt at the final of the name and there is nothing there to choose

Comment: You're basically asking us how to use a `SaveFileDialog`.  You need to do what you can to learn first.  All your questions are addressed in the MSDN documentation for the `SaveFileDialog` class.  VS has a Help menu for a reason.  Use it first when you need help and then use sites like this for the hard stuff that can't be answered simply by reading documentation or web searches.